# RMeCabが日本語ではうまくいきません。

Tags: r

質問：日本語に対してRMecCabをうまく動かせるようにしたい。

RMeCabパッケージの関数を日本語のテキストデータに対して実行すると以下のようになり失敗します。
極楽not foundとなっていますが、実際には極楽は存在します。ちなみに英語のみのテキストデータに対してはうまく動きます。

```
> library("RMeCab")
> r <- collocate("kumo.txt", node = "極楽",span = 3)
file = kumo.txt 
極楽 not found
```

kumo.txtを保存する時に文字コードUTF-8を確認。
[image: ![画像の説明をここに入力]

R-studioの文字コードUTF-8を確認。
[image: ![画像の説明をここに入力]

Notepad++というソフトでエンコードを確認。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: `kumo.txt` の文字コードが CP932(Shift_JIS) だったりしませんか？

Comment: kumo.txtの文字コードは何ですか？デフォルトではShift-JISになっていると思いますが？

Comment: ご返信ありがとうございます。文字コードがUTF-8であることを上記のようにして、kumo.txtとR-studioの双方で確認したつもりなのですが、これが正しい確認方法かは自信がないです。

Comment: kumo.txtにBOMはついていますでしょうか？BOM有りと無しとで動作が変わるか試してみてください。https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21624796/read-a-utf-8-text-file-with-bom

Comment: Notepad++というソフトをダウンロードしてみて、UTF-8かUTF-8ーBOMか確認してみました。確認方法があってるかは不明ですが、UTF-8になってるような気がします。画面を添付します。

Answer (score 1):

Windows上のRMeCabはUTF-8ではなくShift−JISを想定して作られています。
解析対象のテキストデータkumo.txtをUTF-8でなく、ANSIで保存し直すとうまくいきました。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: 「Windows上のRMeCabはUTF-8ではなくShift−JISを想定して作られています」、なんと吃驚仰天。。。

Comment: 日本語処理を行うなら、docker を使ってlinux環境の中で実行すればWindowsでもsjis地獄から抜け出せますよ https://hub.docker.com/r/rocker/rstudio